# Were Carol's potential new suit colour schemes references to anything?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019, captain-marvel

In *Captain Marvel* we see Monica playing around with Carol's suit to change the colour scheme. She goes through 4 or 5 of them before eventually deciding to copy Monica's t-shirt colour scheme and go with that.

Were any of the previous colour schemes references to something else? Perhaps from her comic book origins and the long history of the character?

Answer (score 7):

After a bit of a look around and trying to remember what the different colour schemes were I have found out the following. However, they might not be exact ones because of this but I think they are pretty much right and were the ones shown.

#### Red/Black - Ms. Marvel

This is a reference to Carol's origins as Ms. Marvel.

[image: Ms. Marvel flying in her red/black costume]
<sub>*Click to enlarge.*</sub>

#### Black/Silver - Monica Rambeau

This is a reference to when Monica, yes the young Monica we see in the film, takes up the mantle as Captain Marvel.

[image: Monica's black and silver Captain Marvel outfit]
<sub>*Click to enlarge.*</sub>

#### Black/Neon - Monica Rambeau/Spectrum?

This one is probably not a reference to anything in particular and is more there for "fun". However, Monica also has the current alias "Spectrum" in the comics so this suit could be a reference to the name as it is a "spectrum of colours".

#### Green/White - Mar-Vell

This is almost certainly a reference to Mar-Vell's original white and green costume, the knowing look by Carol when Monica selects it hints at this as well.

[image: Mar-Vell's original white and green outfit]
<sub>*Click to enlarge.*</sub>